# Splitting a <div> into two <div> horizontally aligned, while the overall is vertically aligned on another <div>

Tags: html, css

This code:

```css
#content {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#primo {
  *display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaaaff;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#secondo {
  *display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="primo">
    some content
    <br />some content
    <br />some content
    <br />
  </div>

  <div id="secondo">
    some
    <br />content
    <br />some
    <br />content
    <br />some
    <br />content
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

is rendered as two `<div>` vertically aligned, one on the top of the other, plotting two different texts.

I would like to split the top-div into two subareas (two further sub-`<div>`) horizontally aligned, to plot within these two different texts.

How to achieve this?

It is like creating a two-lines matrix, whose first line has two columns, and the second line has only one column spanning over the full width.

**EDIT**
I would like to learn the basic code for doing something like this mockup:

[image]

Comment: Can you create a mock up of the desired output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but is this kind of layout you want to create(see the code snippet)?

**EDIT:** edited the code now the same layout but done in divs.
If this is the kind of things you want, I recommend you take a look at Flexbox layout, a good guide here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**EDIT2:** Just saw your mock up picture, it is achievable using the Flexbox layout, but you need to tweak a lot of pixels/percentage/numbers to get the exact layout you want, see example in the second snippet.

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.sameRow {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
.normal {
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="sameRow">Content</div>
        <div class="sameRow">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="sameRow">Content</div>
        <div class="sameRow">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="normal">Content</div>
        <div class="normal">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    width: 200px;
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flexColumn {
    flex-direction: column; 
}
.block {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 40px;
    width: 20px;
}
.a0 {
    width: 80%;
    background: red;
}
.a1 {
    height: 84px;
}
.a2 {
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
}
.a3 {
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
}
.a4 {
    width: 112px;
}
.a5 {
    height: 18px;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="block a0 a1"></div>
        <div class="flexColumn">
            <div class="block a2"></div>
            <div class="block a3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="block "></div>
        <div class="block a4"></div>
        <div class="flexColumn">
            <div class="block a5"></div>
            <div class="block a5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, but I need to achieve the same result with using only <div> elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use float left and float right .

I think is this that you want. check it out :

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/ss7e0aso/`
```